# listening changes to a webtable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I have a table in a website. I have extracted the table content and I have stored that in excel. So after some time I extract the web table again and compare that table with my excel
table to look for any changes or updates in the table

What I want is that I want to find if there is any new row added or any row deleted or any value changes made to a particular column in web table by comparing that to excel table.

So my output would be like:

**This reg no a123(I have a column name reg no in table) was removed and this b113 reg no was added. Name column had some changes. John was changed to Jeny**

I tried some methods but didn't work.
Is there any way I could do that please help me out

Comment: What have you tried until now? Show us your efforts - post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus My code is kinda in my office system. I am in home in a different pc.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I used pandas to compare them but no luck

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.